# pygame.QUIT isn't defined

Tags: python, pygame

Following is my code:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.event.quit()
```

I'm using PyCharm, and it highlights the `QUIT` and says `Cannot find reference 'QUIT' in '__init__.py'`. The program doesn't work as expected as well.

Edit: The code is below. K_LEFT or other keys also show the same error

```
import pygame
def move(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.event.quit()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        for key in keys:
            if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
                self.dirnx = -1
                self.dirny = 0
                self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]
            elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
                self.dirnx = 1
                self.dirny = 0
                self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]
            elif keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                self.dirnx = 0
                self.dirny = -1
                self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]
            elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                self.dirnx = 0
                self.dirny = 1
                self.turns[self.head.pos[:]] = [self.dirnx, self.dirny]
```

The error:

````
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/HasanIsgandarli/PycharmProjects/untitled/Snake.py", line 151, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/HasanIsgandarli/PycharmProjects/untitled/Snake.py", line 147, in main
    s.move()
  File "C:/Users/HasanIsgandarli/PycharmProjects/untitled/Snake.py", line 56, in move
    pygame.event.quit()
AttributeError: module 'pygame.event' has no attribute 'quit'

Process finished with exit code 1```
````

Comment: Post full error log and full example with imports etc.

Comment: PyCharm highlights are not so important. PyCharm can also have mistakes. Better run code and see only error messages.

Comment: As the error says, `pygame.event.quit()` does not exist. Just use `pygame.quit().` If you want to close the program, better `sys.exit()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

`if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
      pygame.display.quit()
      pygame.quit()`